# Is the xception model in keras the best model was describe in the paper?

Tags: deep-learning, keras, conv-neural-network

I read the [Xception](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1610.02357.pdf) paper and in this paper it was mentioned in part 4.7 that best results are achivable without any activation. Now I want to use this network on videos using keras toolbox but the model in keras uses 'ReLU' activation function. Does the model in keras returns best model or it is better to omit the relu layers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are confusing normal activations used for convolutional and dense layers, with the ones mentioned in the paper. Section 4.7 only deals with varying the activation between depth-wise and point-wise convolutions, the rest of the activations in the architecture are kept unchanged.